# ffmpeg open webcam using YUYV but i want MJPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, v4l2, mjpeg

I need ffmpeg to open webcam (Logitech C910) in MJPEG mode, because the webcam can give ~24 fps using the MJPEG "protocol" and only ~10 fps using the YUYV. Can I choose between them using the ffmpeg command line?

```
xx@(none) ~ $ v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : MJPEG
```

My current command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -i hw:3,0 -f video4linux2 -r 20 -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 /tmp/web.avi
```

ffmpeg produces corrupted h264 stream when i record from webcam, but normal h264 strem when i record from x11grab. Another codecs (mjpeg, mpeg4) works well with webcam... But this is another story.

**update** Full ffmpeg's console output: http://pastebin.com/Hzem6CKF (you can see it opens video device in YUV mode, but the device can provide MJPEG outpud also).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can list additional information about what your webcam can output with `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`. You can also show webcam information with ffmpeg using the `-list_formats` input option:

```
$ ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
[...]
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1fb7660] Raw       :   yuyv422 :     YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV) : 640x480 160x120 176x144 320x176 320x240 352x288 432x240 544x288 640x360
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1fb7660] Compressed:     mjpeg :                MJPEG : 640x480 160x120 176x144 320x176 320x240 352x288 432x240 544x288 640x360
```

This webcam from my example can support both raw (`yuyv422`) and compressed (`mjpeg`) formats, and you can tell `ffmpeg` which one you want with the `-input_format` input option.

### Examples

Stream copy the MJPEG video stream (no re-encoding):

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy output.mkv
```

Re-encode the raw webcam video to H.264:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

Same as above but manually choose frame rate and video size (`v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` for available frame rate and video sizes):

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

- See the [video4linux2 input device](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2) documentation for more options.
- If the frame rate being output is lower than expected then add more light: the webcam may be lowering the frame rate to get longer exposures in a dim environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -t 60 -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 /DataVolume/share/Public/v/outputs.mp4
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you expand on this? In particular, what information does it have that LordNekbeard's doesn't? :)

Comment: No need for `-strict -2` unless: 1) your `ffmpeg` is horribly outdated, and 2) you are encoding AAC audio.